# creating a subset of data frame when running a loop

Tags: r, for-loop, subset

I'm quite new in R, trying to find my why around. I have created a new data frame based on the "original" data frame.

```
library(dplyr)
prdgrp <- as.vector(mth['MMITCL'])
prdgrp %>% distinct(MMITCL)
```

When doing this, then the result is a list of Unique values of the column MMITCL. I would like to use this data in a loop sequence that first creates a new subset of the original data and the prints a graph based on this:

```
#START LOOP
for (i in 1:length(prdgrp))
{
# mth[c(MMITCL==prdgrp[i],]
mth_1 <- mth[c(mth$MMITCL==prdgrp[i]),]
# Development of TPC by month 
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
ggplot(mth_1, aes(Date, TPC_MTD))+ geom_line()
}
# END LOOP
```

Doing this gives me the following error message:

```
Error in mth$MMITCL == prdgrp[i] : 
  comparison of these types is not implemented
In addition: Warning:
I `[.data.frame`(mth, c(mth$MMITCL == prdgrp[i]), ) :
  Incompatible methods ("Ops.factor", "Ops.data.frame") for "=="
```

What am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to plot the outputs there is no need to subset the dataframe, it is simpler to just put ggplot in a loop (or more likely use facet_wrap).  Without seeing your data it is a bit hard to give you a precise answer.  However there are two generic iris examples below - hopefully these will also show where you made the error in sub setting your dataframe. Please let me know if you have any questions.

```
library(ggplot2)

#looping example
for(i in 1:length(unique(iris$Species))){
  g <- ggplot(data  = iris[iris$Species == unique(iris$Species)[i], ], 
              aes(x = Sepal.Length, 
                  y = Sepal.Width)) +
    geom_point()
  print(g)
}

#facet_wrap example
g <- ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~Species) 
g
```

However if you need to save the data frames for later use, one option is to put them into a list.  If you only need to save the data frame with in the loop you can just remove the list and use whatever variable name you wish.

```
myData4Later <- list()

for(i in 1:length(unique(iris$Species))){
  myData4Later[[i]] <- iris[iris$Species == unique(iris$Species)[i], ]
  g <- ggplot(data  = myData4Later[[i]], 
              aes(x = Sepal.Length, 
                  y = Sepal.Width)) +
    geom_point()
  print(g)
}
```

Comment: yes your are right. I did not add the full code of what I wish to do, as I'm also making Holt-Winter forecast on the data later that I wish so store. My appoligies for not including this.

Comment: Does the addition above answer your question?  Part of your problem is when you subset the data you use c() inside the [].  There may be other issues, but you would need to post a minimum working example.

Comment: it did solve my question. Thank you very much for your help. Appreciated.